# Assigning an object value to an array

Tags: c#

I want store values of object in to an array, sort it, and then store it back to the same object. Array name is "splitup", I am storing values in variable named as "val". securityAllocationVendorList is a list from where I am getting values.

```
double[] splitup;
Type typefile = securityAllocationVendorList.GetType();
PropertyInfo[] properties = typefile.GetProperties();
foreach (PropertyInfo property in properties)
{
    var name = property.Name;
    var val = property.GetValue(securityAllocationVendorList, null);
}
```

Comment: Welcome!  We need more detail to answer this.  You say securityAllocationVendorList is a list.  Does that mean it is a List<object>, or list of some other known type?  When you say 'values of an object', do you mean all of its properties?  If so, I doubt all the properties will be of type double, and the concept of 'sorting a list' usually assumes the list has objects that are all he same type.  So what do you mean by 'sort'?

Comment: Your "question" is missing a basic ingredient of questions: the question mark. This is a telltale sign that your post is missing information that we need to answer whatever your question is. Please edit your post and add the information.

Comment: securityAllocationVendorList is a List<object>. It contains name and a value. Both are strings. But the value in that list is percentage and it is converted to string. I want to sort the values only, round them up and then store it back in same list. So i thought i can get only that value in an object named as val. I am getting only values in val. For sorting those values and do further calculation i need to store it in an array.

Comment: How can a `List<object>` store 2 strings? What does 'store it back in same list' mean exactly?  It's very unclear.

Comment: it is a dictionary<string, string>